# Space Shuttle 10231 Stability on base

Tags: space, creator

[image: Closeup of Shuttle on base]

I just got (finally) Space Shuttle (10231) and finished building it.  It was a great build and I love it, but the way the Shuttle stands on the base scares the SH*T out of me.  I cannot believe they designed this to just stand on four points (the two SRBs, and the base of the thrusters).

I can just imagine my cat hopping onto the bookcase (or someone bumping into the bookcase) and the shuttle falling to the floor in a 1,000 piece pile of bricks!

Has anyone done any modifications to try and lock this onto the base better?

Comment: Could you confirm if your set as well as instructions state 10213 or 10231 as set number? 10213 indeed had some stability issues.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/1177/space-shuttle-design-issue-and-alternate-building-instructions) there were indeed stability problems with [set #10213](https://brickset.com/sets/10213-1/Shuttle-Adventure), which was originally intended to be a strictly display piece for the 16+ age group.

As a response, the [10213 was retired](https://brickset.com/article/1303/update-on-10231-shuttle-expedition), and a reinforced version ([#10231](https://brickset.com/sets/10213-1/Shuttle-Adventure)) has been sold instead. If you are stuck with the first, unstable edition, you could try applying [these alternative instructions](https://www.flickr.com/photos/smashingbricks/sets/72157626117987545/).

You'll need these parts:
[image]
According to Brickset commenter Enosh_Kasra this service pack can be acquired through LEGO customer service (at least it could be in 2011).

And this is the disassembly and reassembly instruction sheet:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This seems to strengthen the External Tank and its connection to the Shuttle, and does not address the four points of stability you mentioned, but I might be wrong. And the extra strength will definitely reduce the number of sub-assemblies after an Unplanned Rapid Disassembly event.

Comment: Yeah I have the modified version so the tank is solid, I am more referring to the instability of the shuttle on the stand